# Can LinkedList accept an Image Icon?

Tags: java, linked-list

How can I write a GUI  LinkedList program by Java to push Image files instead of other data type items?

For the push instruction I wish to give the name of the image file to add it in to the LinkedList, and set the pop instruction to remove the image ?

Comment: Come on, dude ... [you just asked this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802869/can-stack-accept-an-imageicon-in-java).

Comment: Just to prevent other questions: ArrayList, Vector, HashMap, TreeMap, HashSet, TreeSet .... any basic Java collection can accept objects of type `ImageIcon`. ;)

Answer (score 3):

As you can store any Object in a LinkedList you could either store the Filename as a String, the File Object or the ImageIcon Object in the list. Using [genercis](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/generics-136597.html) makes things easy:

```
List<String> fileAsString = new LinkedList<String>();
List<File> fileObject= new LinkedList<File>();
List<ImageIcon> imageIcon= new LinkedList<ImageIcon>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes [`LinkedList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) accepts Object

Answer (score 1):

You can use generic linked lists from java.util package for type safety.

```
LinkedList<Image> imageList = new LinkedList<Image>();
```

However to be able push by name, you need wrap it around in your own implementation class. And override the push method.